# PyCharm throwing an error when I try to use macports python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, theano, macports

I'm trying to get Theano installed so I can start playing with some cool ML stuff, but I'm running into a problem with PyCharm. I'm following the instructions [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html) to get all the prereqs installed so I can run Theano smoothly, so I've used macports to download numpy and scipy, as well as python 2.7.12. PyCharm was initially set to use the interpreter at usr/bin/python (a different python version I have on my computer from last time I was working in python), but I switched it to go to opt/local/bin/python so that everything would be running from the same macports version.

The problem is, booting up my PyCharm with the macports python gives me this error in the console:

```
/opt/local/bin/python -u /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 60364 60365
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 491, in <module>
    pydevconsole.StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 328, in StartServer
    interpreter = InterpreterInterface(host, client_port, threading.currentThread())
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 469, in get_pydev_frontend
    _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 300, in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 396, in __init__
    super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 495, in __init__
    self.init_completer()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 219, in init_completer
    self.Completer = self._new_completer_200()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 191, in _new_completer_200
    use_readline=self.has_readline,
AttributeError: 'PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'has_readline'

Process finished with exit code 1
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

I've done some googling, but all I can find is people who had this resolved by an update (I just downloaded this python ver so I'm pretty sure it's up to date), and people who haven't had it resolved at all. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. :)

EDIT: Found [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20013) page, where people have been getting similar errors. There's a patch posted, but I can't find the pydev files it references anywhere on my computer. I also downloaded the readline library, and ipython2.7. Still no luck :(

EDIT 2: Fixed it! The problem was with my ipython (5.1), which wasn't compatible with pycharm. I uninstalled it and reverted back to 4.2, which cleared up the errors with using the console, but left the one about the ipython.utils.traitlets package. To fix this, I just disabled pycharm's use of ipython. Everything seems to be working smoothly now!

Comment: In macports do you have the readline library installed?

Comment: I didn't until reading this comment. I just installed it with "sudo port install readline", but that didn't seem to help matters - I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem was with my ipython (5.1), which wasn't compatible with pycharm. I uninstalled it and reverted back to 4.2, which cleared up the errors with using the console, but left the one about the ipython.utils.traitlets package. To fix this, I just disabled pycharm's use of ipython. Everything seems to be working smoothly now!